# Reloading collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview, custom-cell

I am writing an app in Objective C. I have custom cell in collections view. Initially it loads data from SQLite Db and displays it in Collection view within each custom cell. And it displays cells on collection view.

Once I reload collection view the collection view stays in black color.

Code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 3;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self readRowCount:@"SELECT COUNT(label) FROM colour;"];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%d", [arrColour count]);
    CustomViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  //  if (cell == nil) {
    //    cell = [[CustomViewCell alloc]init];
    //}

    cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ [arrColour objectAtIndex:indexPath.item ]label] ];

    CellData *redObj = [arrColour objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CellData *greenObj = [arrColour objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CellData *blueObj = [arrColour objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    float redF = [[redObj red] floatValue];
    float greenF = [[greenObj green] floatValue];
    float blueF = [[blueObj blue] floatValue];
    //NSLog(@"Colours: %f-%f-%f", redF, greenF, blueF);
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:redF/255.0f green:greenF/255.0f blue:blueF/255.0f alpha:1];

    return cell;
}
```

The place I reload data- the button:

```
- (IBAction)btnAdd:(id)sender {
   NSString *myRed = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%1.4f", slideR.value];
   NSString *myGreen = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%1.4f", slideG.value];
   NSString *myBlue = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%1.4f", slideB.value];
    if(txtField != nil){


        [colMain reloadData];
    }
```

The arrColour (Mutable Array) in this situation contains same amount of elements. What does the collection view has been not reloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a good reason you are using Sqlite directly instead of using Core Data, which nicely abstracts most of the low-level persistence complexity away?

Anyway, if you must, here’s how you could get it going with your current approach:

1. Load your Sqlite data into a model, e.g. an `NSArray*` property or instance variable. Initialize and fill the array in `-viewDidLoad` (or later).
2. Change your `datasource` implementations to use that array, e.g. `return [self.colors]` in the `numberOfItemsInSection` `datasource` method.
3. Change (or replace) the model array when you add or replace a model item. Then call `-reloadData` on the collection view.

Some other tips:
  - Are you sure you really want to have 3 sections ("groups" of items) in the collection view? If you actually didn't, just remove your `-numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` implementation altogether.
  - You are getting the same objects three times when you do `arrColors[indexPath.item`. Surely this is not your intention? Consider using `UIColor` as elements of the array, or wrap the color value in a custom `NSObject` subclass.

Hope this gives you some pointers on how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

In fact what I needed to do is to make properties for my custom object 'strong'. That is were I store values for RGB colours- in a custom object.